# Migrating to Apache Tiles 3.x from 2.x

Tags: tiles2, apache-tiles, tiles-3

We are trying to migrate from tiles 2.x to 3.x but facing some problems:

We have used the below tiles defination
In Tiles 2.0

`<tiles:insertDefinition name="header.${countryCode}" ignore="false" />`

But in tiles 3.0 the `ignore="false"` has been removed, so want to know what other alternative exists.  Simply removing `ignore="false"` can result in runtime exceptions.

Here are the javadoc:

**Tiles 2.x**

https://tiles.apache.org/2.2/framework/tiles-jsp/tlddoc/tiles/insertDefinition.html

**Tiles 3.x**

https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tiles-jsp/tlddoc/tiles/insertTemplate.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you confirm that ignore="true" worked on insertDefinition for you when using tiles-2.2 ?

For the moment i can't see that ignore is used in http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tiles/framework/branches/TILES_2_2_X/tiles-jsp/src/main/java/org/apache/tiles/jsp/taglib/InsertDefinitionTag.java?view=markup

Comment: I only looked for documentation of `ignore` in the API, never thought of checking it whether it worked with `ignore="true"`. Thanks for the link, it clearly shows the `ignore` is really ignored in tiles 2.x. Thanks a ton.